Looking to lay a new lawn in the UK that is slow growing
I'm about to create a new lawn in my new house. The area is about 60m2.
I got pretty bored of mowing every 2 weeks in our last house with a similar sized lawn and this house already has an existing lawn at the back of the garden which is probably 70m2 so mowing 130m2 every couple of weeks isn't my idea of fun !
That said we have young kids and have decided to go ahead so I was looking at options that are slow growing.
I see that you can buy non rye grass seed mixes that suggest they grow more slowly. However is the rye grass added to make the grass more hard wearing?
Does anyone have any real world experiences of slow growing grasses either positive or negative?

Artificial turf does not grow at all. 0.032 Acres does not seem like a terrible burden to mow, honestly. The robot mower might be good if you don't want artificial grass.

If you have young kids, the sharpness of the leaves is also a factor. (Whether you want something soft, that's nice to fall over on, or something harsh-to-the touch that discourages uprooting, depends on the kids in question.)

There are slower growing lawn seeds for use in the UK - the slowest is sheep's fescue, but they're not particularly hard wearing and you have children so it's unlikely to cope with foot traffic so well. Usually, slower growing seeds are mixed with other seeds to give a lush, more hardwearing lawn, and even if you grew a lawn exclusively from sheep's fescue, it would still need mowing every 10-14 days in season. Further info here https://www.lawnsmith.co.uk/lawn-care-problems/grass-seed-problems/slow-growing-grass-for-lawns#:~:text=Sheep's%20Fescue%20is%20a%20slow,compared%20to%20other%20grass%20species.
Maybe investigate a robotic lawnmower instead...

"Chewings Fescue" is a slow growing grass.
On the other hand, UK' rainy climate and growth in summer, perhaps better alternative avoid so much lawn, adopt a low maintenace garden.
A "Rain Garden" is a planted depression designed to maximize flow absorption all rainwater that falls in it. Thus potential mitigate flood effects, heavy rain and reduce need extensive mowing.



I would recommend buffalo grass if it's not declared as a weed in your area; it grows relatively slowly, it's a creeping grass that does not grow very tall even when in need of a mow, and once established it's tough as nails. One caveat though - it is hypersensitive to dicamba-based weedkillers.

Buffalo grass is not suited to the UK, climate's too cool.

Darn. It grows well in SE Australia though.
